# Can I disable the window resizing feature on my Mac Catalyst iOS app

Tags: ios, macos, mac-catalyst, uikitformac

I'm migrating my iOS app to support MacCatalyst but I'd like to prevent the window from being resized by the user.

Do you have any tips for that?

Comment: I am also face same issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: No, I haven't @HardikThakkar. It is possible to limit the size for MacOS apps, but apparently not (yet) for iOS apps that were built for mac

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388389/xcode-11-disable-resize-mode-in-catalyst-swift/57398562#57398562

Comment: This is so weird because I have the opposite problem. The app can't be resized and I want to to be resizable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Xcode11 Beta 5, the `UIWindowScene` class started supporting the property `sizeRestrictions`.

If you set `sizeRestrictions.maximumSize` and `sizeRestrictions.minimumSize` to the same value, the window will not be resizable. To do so, just call this in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method (if you're using **UIKit**):

```
    UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.allowsFullScreen = false // optional
    }
```

If you're using **SwiftUI** instead of UIKit, you should actually add it to `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` in your scene delegate.

**Note: You need to run this in OSX 10.15 Beta 5 or later, otherwise it will crash**

Comment: is above code working fine ? i got crash in above code.

Comment: I am using storyboard for design.

Comment: You need to latest 10.15 Beta 5. In previous version it will crash on above line

Comment: This only works for me if I place it in 

```func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
}```

Comment: Same for me @B.Slade . Works in SceneDelegate

Comment: @mat: which version of OSX and XCode are you using?

Comment: @mat: are you using SwiftUI or UIKit?

Answer (score 4):

In a SwiftUI App lifecycle this worked for me:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {

  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
  
  var userSettings = UserSettings()
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .environmentObject(userSettings)
        .environmentObject(KeyboardManager())
        .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
          let verificationCode = url.lastPathComponent
          log.info(" Verification Code: \(verificationCode)")
          userSettings.verificationCode = verificationCode
        })
      .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIScene.willConnectNotification)) { _ in
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        // prevent window in macOS from being resized down
          UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 1000)
          }
        #endif
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The .onReceive here worked very well for me too! I swapped it out with .task, though, and set .maximumSize to be equal minimumSize. Now I have the window the size I want :-)

Answer (score 1):

for Objective-C try

```
for (UIScene* scene in UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes) {
    if ([scene isKindOfClass:[UIWindowScene class]]) {
        UIWindowScene* windowScene = (UIWindowScene*) scene;
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(480, 640);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Steve gave me the answer. Also add disable fullscreen

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIScene.willConnectNotification)) { _ in
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        // prevent window in macOS from being resized down
        UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 1000)
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 1000)
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.allowsFullScreen = false
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: You are literally saved my life!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the file, SceneDelegate.swift, add this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 1268, height: 880)
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = windowScene.sizeRestrictions!.minimumSize
    }
    
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```