# Xcode 11 - Disable resize mode in catalyst swift

Tags: swift, xcode11, uikitformac, mac-catalyst

We are **converting our Swift based iOS app to Mac** compatible using **Catalyst** in Xcode 11.

We are facing an issue in UI when user **resize** app window. So can we **disable resize mode** and give fix frame for app window?

Comment: Who give minus and why ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Beta 5 added a `sizeRestrictions` property to [UIWindowScene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3368166-sizerestrictions?language=objc).

If you set `sizeRestrictions.maximumSize` and `sizeRestrictions.minimumSize` to the same value, the window will not be resizable:

```
windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 640, height: 480)
windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 640, height: 480)
```

The easiest place to add this code is probably `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` in your scene delegate. The `scene` object passed in is a `UIWindowScene`, so just cast it and then set `sizeRestrictions`.

**Note: `sizeRestrictions` are only available in iOS 10.15 Beta 5. This code will crash in older betas.**

Comment: where i need to write above code ? in SceneDelegate file ?

Comment: Thank adam for help, issue is crash issue is solve in macOS Catalina beta 5.

Comment: Yes, your scene delegate is probably easiest. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have same issue trying to disable resize mode for an ios calculator app and trying to convert it to mac by using catalyst . And this solution not working for me .

Comment: In the Xcode 12.2 beta using SwiftUI universal I do not have a SceneDelegate file. Where and how can I insert the code in my @main app file?

Comment: @multitudes Hmm, that’s tricky. You could try @marcselosalloum’s solution, if you are okay having the same settings for all your windows. 

Otherwise… Maybe add a UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor and then use your app delegate’s configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession method to attach a scene delegate? Here’s somebody trying that to mixed results: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656631

Answer (score 1):

You can call this in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
    UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)
    }
```

Comment: to piggy back off this, I have a similar issue, where the user resizes a catalyst project window, I would like to put some code in to redraw some views when the window is resized.  What is the method for this? As this is an iOS project I dont know if there is a function such as 'viewDidResize'?

Comment: @samp17: What are you using to set up the view sizes? Constraints or frames?

Comment: Constraints in storyboards

Comment: @samp17 Check out [viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransitiontosize) in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

for Objective-C try

```
#if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
    for (UIScene* scene in UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes) {
        if ([scene isKindOfClass:[UIWindowScene class]]) {
            UIWindowScene* windowScene = (UIWindowScene*) scene;
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(480, 640);
        }
    }
#endif
```